# Imacros javascript macro execute commands after closed browser

Tags: javascript, if-statement, firefox, imacros

I have an imacros javascript macro that use some if to execute the commands.

This imacros javascript close in automatically firefox if the are some conditions but execute other commands after firefox is closed.

This imacros javascript grab current ip on internet and save it in variable.

Check if the ip grabbed is #EANF# (not extracted) and close firefox.

Compare with a loop the current ip with a list of ip saved in csv and if current ip is already used close firefox.

Update the loop number.

Update some firefox settings.

Run an iim macro.

Save info in csv.

Open a batch file.

With a loop check the current ip to check the connection internet is up.

This imacros javascript have a problem, after closed firefox because an if statement is true run bat file but the batch file will be run only if the if statement will not found.

Why after the firefox will be closed run start.bat ?

The if were inserted to interrupt the execution of the script and to close firefox but note that the bat file is also loaded.

I need to run start.bat only when firefox not will be closed with iimPlayCode ("TAB CLOSE") command.

This is the code

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////// Variables //////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var jsNewLine = "\n"
var Loops = 500

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////// Clear Cookies And Cache With Imacros /////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

iimPlayCode ("CLEAR")

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////// Ip Current Save ///////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

iimPlayCode ("TAB OPEN")
iimPlayCode ("TAB T=2")
iimPlayCode ("URL GOTO=https://ident.me/")
iimPlayCode ("WAIT SECONDS=10")
iimPlayCode ("TAG POS=1 TYPE=PRE ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT")

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////// Save Ip Current In Variable /////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

IpCurrent = iimGetLastExtract(1);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////// Close Tab //////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

iimPlayCode ("TAB CLOSE")

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////// Ip Current #EANF# Close Browser ///////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

if (IpCurrent == "#EANF#")

{
iimPlayCode ("TAB CLOSE")
iimPlayCode ("TAB CLOSE")
iimPlayCode ("TAB CLOSE")
iimPlayCode ("TAB CLOSE")
iimPlayCode ("TAB CLOSE")
iimPlayCode ("PAUSE")
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////// Loop /////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

for (i = 0; i < Loops; i ++ )

{

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////// Macro Code //////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

code = "";
code += "CODE:" + jsNewLine
code += "SET !ERRORIGNORE YES" + jsNewLine
code += "SET !LOADCHECK YES" + jsNewLine
code += "SET !REPLAYSPEED FAST" + jsNewLine
code += "SET !POINTER YES" + jsNewLine
code += "SET !TIMEOUT 30" + jsNewLine
code += "SET !TIMEOUT_TAG 0" + jsNewLine
code += "SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO" + jsNewLine

code += "SET !DATASOURCE F:\\ip_addresses_used.csv" + jsNewLine
code += "SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 2" + jsNewLine
code += "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE " + i + jsNewLine

code += "ADD !EXTRACT {{!COL1}}" + jsNewLine

iimPlay(code);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////// Save Ip Used In Variable ///////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

IpUsed = iimGetLastExtract(1);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////// Display Loop /////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

iimDisplay("Completed Loop " + i)

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/// Compare Ip Current (Extracted) With Ip Used (Csv) //
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

if (IpCurrent == IpUsed)

{
iimPlayCode ("TAB CLOSE")
iimPlayCode ("TAB CLOSE")
iimPlayCode ("TAB CLOSE")
iimPlayCode ("TAB CLOSE")
iimPlayCode ("TAB CLOSE")
iimPlayCode ("PAUSE")
}

}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////// Settings On Firefox /////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

prefs = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch);
prefs.setBoolPref("pdfjs.disabled", true);  // Disable Pdf Js
prefs.setBoolPref("webgl.disabled", true);  // Disable WebGL
prefs.setBoolPref("webgl.enable-webgl2", false);  // Disable WebGL2
prefs.setBoolPref("media.peerconnection.enabled", false); // Disable WebRTC
prefs.setBoolPref("xpinstall.signatures.required", false); // Disable Xpi Addons Signature (For Ras)
prefs.setCharPref("browser.startup.homepage", "about:memory");  // Browser Startup Homepage
prefs.setIntPref("browser.display.use_document_fonts", 0);  // Disable Numbers Of Fonts
prefs.setIntPref("browser.sessionhistory.max_entries", 2); // Disable Tab History

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////// Run Macro //////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

iimPlay ("mymacro.iim")

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////// Save Ip Used /////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

IpNote = "VM-Views-1";
iimSet("IpCurrent", IpCurrent);  // Need It To Store Variable
iimSet("IpNote", IpNote);  // Need It To Store Variable
iimPlayCode ("SET !EXTRACT {{IpCurrent}}\n ADD !EXTRACT {{!NOW:dd-mm-yyyy_hh-nn}}\n ADD !EXTRACT {{IpNote}}\n SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=F:\\ FILE=ip_addresses_used.csv");

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////// Run Bat File /////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"]
                     .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
file.initWithPath("D:\\Programmi Installati\\Macro\\bat\\start.bat");
file.launch();

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////// Checking Connection Status //////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////// Variables //////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var Checks = 100

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////// Loop /////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

for (c = 0; c < Checks; c ++ )

{

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////// Ip Current Save ///////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

iimPlayCode ("TAB OPEN")
iimPlayCode ("TAB T=2")
iimPlayCode ("URL GOTO=https://ident.me/")
iimPlayCode ("WAIT SECONDS=10")
iimPlayCode ("TAG POS=1 TYPE=PRE ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT")

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////// Save Ip Current In Variable /////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

IpCurrent = iimGetLastExtract(1);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////// Close Tab //////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

iimPlayCode ("TAB CLOSE")
iimPlayCode ("WAIT SECONDS=600")

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////// Ip Current #EANF# Close Browser ///////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

if (IpCurrent == "#EANF#")

{
iimPlayCode ("TAB CLOSE")
iimPlayCode ("TAB CLOSE")
iimPlayCode ("TAB CLOSE")
iimPlayCode ("TAB CLOSE")
iimPlayCode ("TAB CLOSE")
iimPlayCode ("PAUSE")
}

}
```

Comment: 'FCIM' as a start, read my Sig (hum, maybe on the iMacros Forum)... - But your Script is a complete "Joke", sorry...!, this is 2019 but it is full of Commands that have been deprecated for at least 10 years...! (And for a few, that I had never heard of, ah-ah...!) - Open a parallel Thread on the iMacros Forum, nbd on SOF will be able to read your Script... I will quote your Thread anyway after 2 or 3 days as your Thread is really a "Collector Item", ah-ah...!, quite interesting for the iMacros Forum though..., miam-miam...!

Comment: Hum OK, and I read your "Scenario Description", but it doesn't really make sense to me to be honest, and I don't even understand your only Qt: "Why after the firefox will be closed run start.bat ?", which again doesn't make sense, or even just grammatically...

Comment: Hi i need to stop script execution after if (IpCurrent == "#EANF#") or if (IpCurrent == IpUsed) in these case i need to stop the execution of script and close firefox and do not continue the script. actually the script continue and execute the bat file.

Comment: Well, "stop script execution" is not complicated, that's automatic and default behaviour with '#EANF#' if you don't use '!ERRORIGNORE', or with 'EVAL()' + 'MacroError()' and also with 'EVENT:FAIL_IF_FOUND'. - And to close FF, you have a Thread on the iMacros Forum with 5 or 6 different ways to do so, and most of those 5 or 6 can be called conditionally, especially if using a '.js' Script.

Comment: + Parallel Thread (C&P) on the iMacros Forum as your Script is a real "Collector Item"...:
 - https://forum.imacros.net/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=30189&p=81766#p81766